# Microservices with express gateway : routes return 404 error

Tags: node.js, express, microservices, express-gateway

My microservice is running in port `3000` and I am trying to proxy the request via `express-js gateway`

But I got a problem with accessing routes in microservice

MICRO SERVICE ROUTE

```
app.use('/sample',(req,res)=>{
   res.json({
     message:'Run with microservice'
   })
})
```

And I am able to access this route `http://localhost:3000/sample`.

Here is my  `gateway.config.yml`.

```
http:
  port: 3004
admin:
  port: 9876
  hostname: localhost
apiEndpoints:
  test:
    host: localhost
    paths: '/test'
serviceEndpoints:
  test:
    url: 'http://localhost:3002/'  
policies:
  - basic-auth
  - cors
  - expression
  - key-auth
  - log
  - oauth2
  - proxy
  - rate-limit
pipelines: 
  test:
    apiEndpoints:
      - test
    policies:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: test
              changeOrigin: true
```

When I try to access my microservice route via  `http://localhost:3004/test/sample` returns `cannot get route error`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in general, make sure to review our [Path Management Piece](https://www.express-gateway.io/docs/policies/proxy/#path-management). This will help you understand what's the PATH that gets forwarded to your service.

Talking specifically about your question — if you want to forward a path that can "continue" beyond the specification, you need to change the path definition from `/test` to `/test*`. This instructs the gateway that the path is not complete and something else might be provided.

Also, on the service side, I'd change the `app.use` to `app.get` so you're listening only for the VERBS you're interested.

Cheers!

Comment: i've changed path to `paths: '/test*'` but still getting 404 error

Comment: The forwarded path to your service is indeed `/test/sample` — in case you want to make it just proxy to `/sample` you need to enable the `stripPath` option in the Proxy policy option. Check out the link I gave you above.

Comment: where can i add the proxy policy argument??

Comment: I suggest you to have a look to our proxy policy page so you can see where to put correctly all the options.

Comment: @Vincenzo Do you have a handbook with examples that is microservices with nodejs?

Comment: I do not, unfortunately.

Answer (score -2):

I would go with Janus - https://hellofresh.gitbooks.io/janus/ for API Gateway Management as it specializes specifically on that. Have a look and let me know what you think.

Comment: The question is about express-gateway i am asking a solution for my current problem not a replacement